# Android - how to lay out a list view item similar to iOS table view cell with image, title and subtitle?

Tags: android, uitableview, listview, layout

I'm trying to lay out an Android list view cell similar to the common iOS design - an image on the left, and two labels next to the image:
[image]

**How can I achieve an Android cell layout like the basic iOS cell with image, title and subtitle?**

However, I'm not sure what is the proper layout to use to accomplish this task. Here's what I'm trying, and it does not align elements properly:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/api"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.47">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/side_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/side_button_size"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:background="@drawable/close_red" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="246dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="This is title label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="This is subtitle label" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use this tutorial from Vogella: [Custom ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an horizontal `LinearLayout` that contains an `ImageView` and another (vertical this time) `LinearLayout` that contains the 2 `TextView`s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Simply put:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|           | TextView1 |
| ImageView |           |
|           | TextView2 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a RelativeLayout, you can specify each child's relative position. Here's an example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/side_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/side_button_size"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="@drawable/close_red" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="246dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/image"
        android:text="This is title label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:text="This is subtitle label" />
</RelativeLayout>
```